# Mersenne Cousins (numbers primes)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

What are the prime numbers obtained by: $$2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{\vdots^{2}}}}}}} + 9$$

The numbers are $~11~$ and $~13~$. I think I would have to apply Mersenne's cousins, but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$a_1=2$$
$$a_{i+1}=2^{a_i}$$
I am assuming that you are trying to find all $i\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_i+9$ a prime number.

Evidently, $i=1,2$ satisfy the given condition. By induction, $4|a_i\forall i\geq 2$ and therefore,
$$\forall i\geq 3 \exists m_i\in\mathbb N \ \ such\ \ that \ \ a_i=2^{4m_i}$$
Therefore, *for all* $i\geq 3, a_i$ is a power of $16$, and hence, have $6$ as the unit digit, showing that 
$$5|(a_i+9)\forall i\geq 3$$

Hence, $11$ and $13$ are the only primes of required type.